# socket.error: [Errno 99] Address not available..Get this error while trying to link a container with another container of CouchDB in Docker

Tags: python, docker, webserver, couchdb

I am trying to make a Docker Image of a Web Application which is based on python. As I am trying to link the official CouchDB container with the Docker Container that I have created I am getting the **"Address not available error"**. docker ps -a shows me that the couchdb is working in a perfect way.
The command that I have used in the terminal is:

```
 docker run -p 5984:5984 --name my-couchdb -d couchdb

 docker run --name my-couchdb-app --link my-couchdb:couchdb webpage:test
```

My Docker File for webpage:test is given below:

```
FROM python:2.7.15-alpine3.6

RUN apk update && \^M
        apk upgrade && \^M
        apk add bash vim sudo
RUN mkdir /home/WebDocker/
ADD ./Webpage1 /home/WebDocker/Webpage1

ADD ./requirements.txt /home/WebDocker/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /home/WebDocker
RUN pip install -r /home/WebDocker/requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x /home/WebDocker/Webpage1/main.py

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["python","/home/WebDocker/Webpage1/main.py"]
```

Comment: What is the content of `/home/WebDocker/Webpage1/main.py` ?

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron It is basically lauch a Web application in the local server. If it run succesfully I can load a  Webpage at 0.0.0.0:5000..